# Не подключается Flurry в Swift'овом проекте

Tags: ios, swift

Добавляю Flurry (только аналитику) в сфивтовый проект по мануалу:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/ios-manual/

Выполняю все пункты. При сборке выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Попробуйте очистить проект.

Comment: конечно пробовал )

Comment: Вручную или через  Pod?

Comment: вручную. по этой ссылке ручное подключение. Через поды, честно говоря, не понял что именно в бридже прописать надо - какой путь должен быть у import'а до Flurry.h (ни один вариант у меня не сработал)

Comment: так и не разобрался как добавить flurry руками, добавил через pod: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851025/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-bridging-header-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-flurry/851247#851247