# Каким должен быть bridging header для Flurry?

Tags: ios, swift, bridge, cocoapods

Подключаю Flurry через Cocoapod в проект на Swift. pod install скачивает библиотеку в проект, но не получается сделать корректную запись в bridge-файле для FlurrySDK (с остальными obj-c зависимостями никаких проблем нет):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как/где следует смотреть правильный путь для строки импорта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**В данном случае bridging header не нужен**. Добавив фреймворк через pod, можно просто заимпортить его в нужном контролле и использать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]